# Run python command from bash ubuntu

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, odoo

I have installed odoo 8.0 (formerly openerp) source in my ubuntu 14.04
When i try this command (to run odoo server) from terminal

```
python odoo.py
```

it was run normally.

But, how can i know the return value of python command?
i want to see if the command running normally, or
it is raise an exception?

So i can make *.sh file to run that command.

I have tried this code

```
if [ -f odoo.py ]; then
    python odoo.py
    rc=$?;
    if [ $rc !=0 ]; then
        echo "Error when starting odoo-server,"
        echo "Odoo-server not started."
    else
        sleep 1
        echo "Odoo-server started."
    fi
else
    echo "Cannot found odoo.py"
    echo "Odoo-server not started."
fi
```

but, when the command fail
it is always give me this output

```
Odoo-server started
```

Any one can help me?

Comment: See the config for the path of the logfile and read it.

Comment: *How* does Odoo fail? Does it throw an exception? Some other failure that causes it to just plain exit? If `odoo.py` just exits, is it documented to exit with a non-zero exit code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spacing is wrong:

```
    if [ $rc !=0 ]; then
```

Should be:

```
    if [ $rc != 0 ]; then
```

But that is a text test, an arithmetic test would be:

```
    if [ $rc -ne 0 ]; then
```

or preferably:

```
    if (( rc != 0 )); then
```

However, a better way would be:

```
if python odoo.py
then
    sleep 1
    echo "Odoo-server started."
else
    echo "Error when starting odoo-server," >&2
    echo "Odoo-server not started." >&2
fi
```

Comment: thanks, i have tried your first solution and it work for me

Comment: But please note the better way to do it - there is no need to capture `$?` and test it explicitly.